# Instagram screencast video

Tags: api, instagram, screencast

I'm coding a new app working with the Instagram API.
on the permissions panel, it asks me how I'm going to use the app, and asks me to put a video to a screen-cast of how it work will?

[image: http://support.heateor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Instagram-Login-Permission-Review.png]

Well, I don't have a ready working example because I am simply trying to make it. Where should I get the screen-cast video explaining how the app will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permission panel should only be modified once you have the final flow ready.

This is only used for submitting your app for review so as to change the app's status from sandbox to live(should you want to make it live).

So since you are in development phase, don't bother about it now. You can use the API endpoints as you would expect after making it live (mind the sandbox factor, for more details,check out: [Instagram API doesn’t find any liked posts for sandbox users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886881/instagram-api-returns-empty-data-for-sandbox-users-when-trying-to-access-liked-c/33887790#33887790)).

After testing, once you're satisfied with your flows, you can proceed for the use case (described in [documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/)) and the screencast of your app in motion.

Hope it helps!