# Empty success response with a correct access token from Instagram API

Tags: api, instagram

I'm trying to get the user's followers, but I receive an empty response.
Does anyone know what's wrong?

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=XXXXXX

```
{"pagination":{},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

Thank you

Comment: maybe because you aren't following anyone? This isn't the followers api.

Comment: I'm following more than 150 people

Comment: may be in sandbox mode only authorized users are shown in list, try adding a user u follow to your sandbox and try

Comment: do you know how to add an user to the sandbox?

Comment: look in instagram developer site for your app

Comment: Did you try accessing the followers list of another user?

Answer (score 4):

The reason maybe you are in sandbox mode. Instagram APIs behave differently in Sandbox mode. One of those **different** behaviors is the screening / visibility of users on Instagram and / or their data set access.

So here's how you add a Sandbox user:

- Go to [Instagram Developer](http://www.instagram.com/developer/) and login with your developer account
- Click on *Manage clients*
- Click on the Edit button for the app you want to add Sandbox users.
- Click on Sandbox tab and enter the username / email id of an Instagram user and press enter
- Click on Save Changes

Regarding the **Sandbox** concept few things to note:

- You can only add 20 users per app
- Any user can be sandbox user for a maximum of 5 apps.
- You can only pull the recent data belonging to sandbox users in sandbox mode

For more details, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886881/instagram-api-returns-empty-data-for-sandbox-users-when-trying-to-access-liked-c) which explains the concept in a case by case basis or for more details, check out [Sandbox Instagram Documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/)

Hope it helps!