# Instagram API only returns 1 item

Tags: instagram-api

I have this URL here with my access key,

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/MY_USER_ID/media/recent?access_token=MY_ACCESS_KEY
```

but it only returns 1 item.

I have googled for a solution, but can't seem to find one.
This was **working** about a **month ago** and now it's broken.

I have deleted the old client, created a new one and generated a new access_token.
But it stays with the same result.

My question is:
**How can I get the same results like a month ago?**

*I got my access token via [freevision.me/instagram](http://freevision.me/instagram/)

and my client ID by following these instructions [doc.freevision.me/adventure/knowledge-base/get-instagram-client-id](http://doc.freevision.me/adventure/knowledge-base/get-instagram-client-id/).*

Comment: Are you looking for https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Get the most recent media published by a user.
The public_content scope is required if the user is not the owner of the access_token.

REQUIREMENTS
Scope: public_content
PARAMETERS
ACCESS_TOKEN    A valid access token.
MAX_ID  Return media earlier than this max_id.
MIN_ID  Return media later than this min_id.
COUNT   Count of media to return.

[instagram api](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)

and here media endpoint (see "count")

[Instagram media](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent)

Comment: I have tried your URL example and it did not work :(

Comment: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/32795371/media/recent?count=5&access_token=12345 what kind of problem you have?

Comment: Its only returning 3 items and the pagination is empty

Comment: the data is not empty, it returns 3 items, empty pagination, meta code 200

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482578/empty-success-response-with-a-correct-access-token-from-instagram-api

Comment: So I have to add another user to my sandbox? Which user? I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

The right endpoint is this: [get_user_media_recent](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent) and if your app is in sandbox mode, you will need to enable the user as a sandbox user (you can do that from the settings of instagram app: `Manage Client > Edit > Sandbox tab`)

Anyway, in the sandbox mode, the API not return the pagination because has a [limit of 20 media](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/).