# Why am I not getting any data from an Instagram API request though I am a accepted sandbox user?

Tags: instagram-api

This question is similar to [Instagram API doesn’t find any liked posts for sandbox users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886881/instagram-api-returns-empty-data-for-sandbox-users-when-trying-to-access-liked-c).

When I send:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/user-ID/media/recent/?access_token=access-token&count=20
I get back:
{"pagination": {}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
The user has been accepted into the sandbox for this client so why am I not getting any data?

Comment: is the user-ID you are passing accepted in sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by removing the user from the sandbox and adding him back in again.