# Instagram user endpoint returns no media

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get my recent media throught user endpoint https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=my_access_token , while using my app in sanbox mode.

Instagram api always returns

```
{"pagination": {}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

My instagram profile is open even for non-authorized users. Why do I receive no data, any ideas?

Comment: Based on the URL you provided, it looks correct. That response means the scope from sandbox can't see any of your data: it thinks you don't have any photos/videos uploaded. Stupid question, I know, but do you definitely have any photos/videos on your account?

Comment: Try uploading a new photo/video to your account. It may not recognize any media you uploaded before creating your application.

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886881/instagram-api-returns-empty-data-for-sandbox-users-when-trying-to-access-liked-c