# I want to build analytics for my own Instagram account

Tags: amazon-web-services, integration, instagram, analytics

I need to create analytics for my own account on Instagram, and upload it into the Amazon Redshift
The problem is

This option is disabled in app review screen
[image]
So what are options that I have to do that?
I was thinking about my own client for Instagram using my own app credentials, looks like this is impossible?
So the only one option I have is to use 3rd party analytic tools, and then somehow export the results into the Redshift?

Comment: Why this question has been downvoted? Please do provide reasons for downvoting. Marking it down simply because it doesn't interest you is gross.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for your own Instagram account, you don't need to go live. You can keep your app in sandbox mode.

Comment: The problem is
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886881/instagram-api-doesn-t-find-any-liked-posts-for-sandbox-users
They do not provide full information i need